# Select box border radius not working on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, tablet, mozilla, css

I'm just doing a bit of cross-browser and cross-device testing for my website and I've noticed that on Galaxy Tab 3's my select boxes have no border-radius.

Having put a breakpoint in my code I can see that this browser is a Mozilla browser. I've also read that on Android you need to separate the border-radius into it's individual corner so I have done that.

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
```

This still doesn't seem to work. A simple border-radius works everywhere else on my site except select boxes so I'm jsut wondering if anyone can tell me whether having a border radius on a select box is even supported on Android's default browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
```

more about boders for mozilla [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius)